# Error while creating object for inner class (class within nested class)

Tags: java, inner-classes

This is the code which I'm trying; I'm getting error on line "***outer.inner1.inner2 innerobj2= outerobj.new inner2();***".

Can anyone please confirm what is the error and syntax for object creation for nested class methods?

```
class outer {

  public void outerDisplay() { 
    System.out.println("Statement from outer class");
  }

  class inner {
    public void innerDisplay() {
        System.out.println("Statement from inner class");   
    }
  }

  class inner1 {
    public void inner1Display() {
        System.out.println("Statement from inner1 class");
    }

    class inner2 {
        public void inner2Display() {
            System.out.println("Statement from inner2 class");  
        }
    }
  }
}


public class InnerOuter {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    outer outerobj=new outer();
    outerobj.outerDisplay();

    outer.inner innerobj=outerobj.new inner();
    innerobj.innerDisplay();

    outer.inner1 innerobj1=outerobj.new inner1();
    innerobj1.inner1Display();

    **outer.inner1.inner2 innerobj2= outerobj.new inner2()**;
    innerobj2.inner2Display();      
  }
}
```

Comment: new is always first, the qualifying name for class comes after that.

so outer.inner innerobj = new outerobj.inner();

Comment: Hi @TaaviKivimaa, "outerobj.new inner()" and "outerobj.new inner1()" worked fine. But not working for nested class. Please confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `inner2` is an inner class for `inner1` not for `outer`.
So to create instance of `inner2` you need instance of `inner1` like this:

```
outer.inner1.inner2 innerobj2= innerobj1.new inner2();
```

or

```
outer.inner1.inner2 innerobj2= outerobj.new inner1().new inner2();
```

Comment: thnx Ivan. Worked :)